# use egrep with long pattern list in bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I want to search whether some key words exists in hundreds of xml files, I want to use the following script to handle this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

find . -name '*.xml' |xargs egrep -n "HERE IS LONG LIST(word1|word2|...)" > result
```

I got the error msg as:

```
xargs: a single arg was greater than the max arglist size of 2048 characters
```

So I changed the long list into 3 parts and it becomes:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

find . -name '*.xml' |xargs egrep -n "LIST_1" > result
find . -name '*.xml' |xargs egrep -n "LIST_2" >> result
find . -name '*.xml' |xargs egrep -n "LIST_3" >> result
```

Any better ways to handle this to avoid the pattern list seperation thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better approach would be store all of your matching patterns in a file and use recursive grep with `-f` switch:

```
grep -n -f patternFile -R --include=*.xml .
```

Comment: I never know there is a --include option, something I am looking for:)

Comment: @lzprgmr: `--include=<file-patterns>` is very useful for recursive grep when its not possible to use: `grep -R "foo" *.txt` type of grep command.

Comment: right, with --include, this "find | xargs grep" is never needed.

Answer (score 1):

grep --help:

> f, --file=FILE           obtain PATTERN from FILE

So you can:

```
echo "HERE IS LONG LIST(word1|word2|...)" > pattern.txt
find . -name '*.xml' |xargs egrep -n  -f pattern.txt > result
```